# How to add accuracy percentage in the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currenty my graph look like this

[image: Currenty my graph look like this]

But I want it to show accuracy percentage per epoch in a height chart like this

[image: like this]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might be interested in [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and checking out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the graphing part to matplotlib.pyplot.bar

> https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html